# Select with a submit button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am working with a select button which shows users and a submit button when the user is chosen it redirects to the edit page for the user. I am wondering if it's a better way to show it with twitter bootstrap. 
Maybe a select button which show default "Rediger Bruker" and when user is selected it will direct to the edit page.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/edit_user', 'method' => 'GET')) }} 
        {{ Form::select('empId', $emps) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Rediger Bruker') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry but I didn't get what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a bootstrap-based alternative to a standard HTML form? You could try using [button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) instead.

Comment: Could you please show how that will be done in laravel ? thanks, appriciete it.

Comment: There are many packages for integrating Bootstrap with Laravel: http://packalyst.com/packages/tag/bootstrap . As long as you can create <button> elements and apply the CSS classes shown in the example that I linked, it should be pretty straightforward.